# How to store a JWT and how to use it in cookies

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, cookies, jwt

I have a Django REST backend and React frontend. My submit function is the following:

```
handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    const response = await login(username, password);
    console.log(response.data.token);
};
```

response.data.token is **successfully** returning a token but my question is:

**How do I store it to use in another HTTP requests? (Using the cookie solution)**

Comment: I guess your server should directly put it into a cookie.

Comment: How can I do that? I really do not know the code to achieve that.

Comment: how does your jango code look like?

Comment: I am using djangorestframework-jwt. So the only code is path("getToken/", obtain_jwt_token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with `universal-cookie`

My final code is:

```
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();

...

handleSubmit = async event => {
   event.preventDefault();
   const { username, password } = this.state;
   const response = await login(username, password);
   cookies.set("access_token", response.data.token);
};
```